# Testcase error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Hi i am learning to write test-cases, I started small test-cases for small programs.Iam trying a program

```
require 'test/unit'
class YearTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
def test_hours(m)
  p =  Year.new
  assert_equal(p.hours,m)
  # assert_equal(p.hours,8784)
end
end
class Year
  def hours(a)
    d = 24
    if (a%400 == 0)
   return   h = d * 366
    else
     return h = d * 365
    end
    puts h
  end
end
puts "enter a year"
n = gets.to_i
y = Year.new
y.hours(n)
```

and when i run this program in netbeans am getting error in test-case..can anybody help in solving this??

Answer (score 0):

Your test case needs to specify a particular case; it's not intended to be done interactively as you are trying to do.

Something like this would do:

```
require 'test/unit'

class YearTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_hours
    y = Year.new
    assert_equal 8760, y.hours(2001)
    assert_equal 8784, y.hours(1996)
  end
end
```

Comment: Where can i learn about writing this testcases? can you please tell me Jeremy?

Comment: Hmm. This section of the Wikibook on Ruby seems reasonable. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Unit_testing

And it's an old video, but I think it's still a good demonstration of how to do test-driven development with Test::Unit. http://screencasts.textmate.org/ruby_quiz_screencast.mov